# The text "index" is getting displayed instead of the contents of my index.html file

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this method in my RestController:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public Mono<String> index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("images", imageService.findAllImages());
    return Mono.just("index");
}
```

When I run my applicaiton I get a page with nothing but the text `index` in the top left corner. If I update `return Mono.just("index");` to `return Mono.just("foo");` then `foo` is displayed in the top left corner.

I had expected the file `resources/templates/index.html` to display in the browser. How do I fix this?

Comment: Is it annotated with `Controller` or `RestController` annotation ? Please try once with `Controller` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Like Paras has mentioned, the main issue is probably the incorrect annotation on top of your controller class.

`@RestController` and `@Controller` behave differently when it comes to template processing.

`@RestController` just returns basically your object (in this case the one that is produced by the `Mono.just(...)`) that is typically converted into JSON or plain text (depending on the settings).

The `@Controller` annotation generally means that the return of your controller method should be treated as the path from the template root to an `HTML` template. In this case you don't really need the `Mono.just()` construction (which iirc creates flux for reactive development) - simply return a `String` like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    private ImageService imageService;

    @RequestMapping( "/" ) // could also be @GetMapping( "/" )
    public String index( Model model ) {
        model.addAttribute("images", imageService.findAllImages());
        return "index";
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setImageService( ImageService imageService ) {
        this.imageService = imageService;
    }
}
```

Also I couldn't really understand why exactly you tried to use Rest Controller to display a page. If you wanted to load page contents asynchronously you could just define a simple controller and call the specified URL as an `ajax get`. But note that at this approach you would get a full page (with `<html>`, `<head>` and etc.) inside your page again. To prevent that wrap your content in your `index.html` like this:

```
<!-- head, meta etc -->
<body>
    <th:block th:fragment="content">
        <!-- page content goes here -->
    </th:block>
</body>
```

and in your `index( Model model )` method in controller change your return string to `"index :: content"`.

If this doesn't help please provide your thymeleaf bean definition.